# Regular Expression Not Removing URL From Tweet Text

Tags: python, regex, url, twitter

I have downloaded my tweets history and I'm cleaning data for special characters and url. I'm using regex to do this, but the regex for some url is not working. it removes some but not all, here's the regex I'm using which is a function that returns the tweet without special char and url.

```
   return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +) | http\S+", " ", tweet).split())
```

take for example tweets like this (had to change url link otherwise it will not let post)

```
"RT @RobertDeNiroUS: i want to watch the game... \uD83E\uDD2A https://someurl https://someurl"
```

It will remove the first url but not the second one... same here

```
"face detection in Android Studio #AndroidDev #100DaysOfCode\nhttps://someurl https://someurl"
```

Comment: Is there a typo or you really have so many spaces in the pattern in `) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +) | h`?

Comment: Do you need help with anything?  Please provide more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew check the description... I implemented my own regex. I did achieved it, though

Comment: Please post a code snippet showcasing the issue.